# fputs with #include "test.txt" - compilation error

Tags: c, gcc

`text.txt` file contains 1 line

```
ooo
```

This is the code:-

```
fputs (
#include "test.txt"
,stdout
);
```

Compile Error :

```
1:1: error: ‘ooo’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: Quotes, obviously...Unless `ooo` is a variable.

Comment: What @EugeneSh. said. And then, how did you get the idea to write something like this? Add quotes and it works, but the only **sane** way would be to use `#define` for your filename...

Comment: All would be made clear if you compiled with the options that preserves a copy of the the expanded source.

Comment: What arfe you trying to achieve? I think you should start reading some C text book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `#include` will include the content of your file in place of the statement. So your code would be interpreted as :

```
fputs (
ooo
,stdout
);
```

The error makes sense, because apparently, `ooo` is not something you have defined earlier.

If you meant to print the actual string `ooo`, you should surround it by quotes in your txt file, so it becomes `"ooo"`.

Answer (score 1):

From [**6.10.2p3**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.2p3)

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # include "q-char-sequence" new-line
> ```
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the
>   source file identified by the specified sequence between the `"`
>   delimiters.

Here the content was `ooo` and the compiler didn't understand what this `ooo` meant. It never saw its declaration.